# Обновление DataGridView в C#

Tags: c#, access

Добавляю данные. Данные добавляются, но изменения не отображаются в `DataGridView`. Отображаются только при перезапуске программы.

```
 DataRow newContactRow = fr1.zooparkDataSet.Tables["Animal"].NewRow();

            newContactRow["Name"] = textBox1.Text;
            newContactRow["ID_Klass_zver"] = selectedItem1.ToString();
            newContactRow["ID_Tip_zver"] = selectedItem2.ToString();
            newContactRow["ID_Korm_zver"] = selectedItem3.ToString();
            fr1.zooparkDataSet.Tables["Animal"].Rows.Add(newContactRow);
            fr1.animalTableAdapter.Update(fr1.zooparkDataSet.Animal);
            fr1.animalTableAdapter.Fill(fr1.zooparkDataSet.Animal);
            fr1.animalDataGridView.Refresh();
```

Comment: А на каком событии у вас обновление висит?

Comment: @Sv_t, пробую последними двумя строчками обновить

Comment: Это я понял. Я имею ввиду, когда Вы добавляете строку? Заполнили поля, а дальше что? Нажали кнопку какую-то?

Comment: Да, все это происходит в событие кнопки(при нажатие на её)

Comment: Метод [Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) не вызывает обновление (перепривязку) данных! Он вызывает прорисовку поверхности, т. е. по сути, генерирует событие [Paint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx). В данном случае он бесполезен, уберите его вызов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте заново присвоить `DataSource`:

```
fr1.animalDataGridView.DataSource = null;
fr1.animalDataGridView.DataSource = fr1.zooparkDataSet.Tables["Animal"];
```

Чтобы при этом не произошла автоматическая генерация полей грида придайте значение свойства `AutoGenerateColumns = false`:

```
fr1.animalDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `BindingList<T>` таким образом:

```
var data = new BindingList<object>();
fr1.animalDataGridView.DataSource = data;
data.Add(item1);
data.Add(item2);
```

При добавлении элементов `DataGridView` обновится самостоятельно.